# unable to run ipython notebook, receive import errror

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

ipython itself works when i run it but when i run at the mac command prompt the following command i get a import error:

```
ipython notebook
```

below is the error:

```
    { $ipython notebook               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ipython==3.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 573, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/application.py", line 369, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 471, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 402, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 30, in <module>
    check_for_zmq('13', 'IPython.html')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/IPython/utils/zmqrelated.py", line 12, in check_for_zmq
    raise ImportError("%s requires pyzmq >= %s"%(required_by, minimum_version))
ImportError: IPython.html requires pyzmq >= 13
```

i have ran conda update anaconda and i have updated ipython but the error persists. my end goal is just to open notebook via chrome.

update if i try to open notebook fro spyder this is what i get:

[image]

Comment: You have anaconda installed, but by the looks of your output you are executing ipython notebook in the base mac install of python.  What happens when you open Anaconda's Launcher and run Ipython notebook from there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `pyzmq`, that is separate to ipython:

```
sudo pip install -U pyzmq
```

Comment: after the install i get a confirmation as follows :Requirement already up-to-date: pyzmq in /Users/uen449/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: What about your system python?

Comment: how would i update my system python, how is it done ? the  pip command you gave me does not differentiate based on which python i have.

Comment: @j2emanue, the easiest way is probably to download https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/archive/master.zip unnzip and python setup.py install using your system python